# The Exasol ADO.Net driver doesn't work with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, exasolution

I can't connect to an Exasol Database using .NETCore, but I *can* using the full framework.

To Reproduce:

- Install the EXASOL 6.0.2 ADO.NET Driver from here: https://www.exasol.com/portal/display/DOWNLOAD/6.0
- In Visual Studio 2017, Create a new project /C#/.NET Core/.NET Framework 4.5.2/Console App (.NET Core)
- Add reference to the Exasol ADO.NET Driver: c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EXADataProvider\5.0.0.0__ec874333d1454516\EXADataProvider.dll
- Add these two lines to Main:

  ```
  var cnx = new Exasol.EXADataProvider.EXAConnection();
  cnx.Open();
  ```
- The compiler generates this error on the cnx.Open():

  > Error CS0012 The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=**2.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I've tried installing NuGet packages: System.Data.Common, System.Data.SqlClient, EntityFramework,... No change.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you try to contact their customer support? If the provider doesn't support NET Core they should know that very well.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, yes, I tried to contact Exasol first, but they have been unresponsive so far.